# How to correctly delete Model object field in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

Hello I want to delete my field :

```
tag_number = models.PositiveIntegerField('Tag number', validators=[
        MinValueValidator(1),
        MaxValueValidator(MAX_TAG_NUMBER),
    ])
```

and write fo this method:

```
# @require_POST
def book_tag(request, pk):
    book = get_object_or_404(Book, pk=pk)
    book.tag_number = **book.tag_number.delete()**
    book.tag_number = book.generate_tag()
    book.save()
    return redirect('book:book-list')
```

But it delete all Book Model!I want to delete just the field 'tag_number'.

Comment: why do you want to delete tag number field if are you generating again? you can make  
 `book.tag_number = None` ...   or generate without doing this line just remove this line  `book.tag_number = book.tag_number.delete()`

Comment: @ShotikoAkhlouri it is writes me 'int' object has no attribute 'delete'

Comment: yeah, *book.tag_number* check this what is it! in your way it`s int and you are calling *delete method* of itenger. integer dont have delete method that`s why. in your code change this line `book.tag_number = book.tag_number.delete()` to this `book.tag_number = None`.
IF you want to delete tag_number of your Model just remove that field from `models.py` and then make migrations. 
another way you should learn python and then django!